# Insert new html element in a list at a specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have this example: **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Alchemyistic/pen/mEVxXd)**

How do I make it so that for example if the new random number is 20 it gets added after 24 but before 19?

Is there an "elegant" way to do it or do I have to select all the `li` elements, go through them, and prepend at the first element that has a lower data-num?

Thanks.

//EDIT:

Ended up doing this because I didn't want to empty the whole div and re-populate it again, I think this is the simplest way to do it:

```js
$('ul > li').each(function(i){
  if($(this).data('num') < newNum){
    $(this).before(template);
    return false; //stop .each
  }
  if(i == $('ul > li').length - 1){
    $(this).after(template);
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/Alchemyistic/pen/NrNKLZ

Comment: I think you're talking about putting a new <li>20</li> element in the correct order in a list. Can you give an example of input and output html for us who have not had coffee yet? I'm guessing that ordered or unordered list will have to be in its own <div> with a unique id, so you can address that specific list. Or maybe the <ul> or <ol> can have it's own unique id like: `<ul id="unique">`.

Comment: Select the appropriate element and use jQuery's `.after()` method, e.g. `$('li[data-num=19]').after(template);`

Comment: You want something like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRrMqN)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using a while loop.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var newNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
  var template = '<li data-num="' + newNum + '">' + newNum + '</li>';
  // flag for while loop
  var found = false,
    // get first eleemnt from list
    $ele = $('ul li[data-num]').first(),
    last = false;
  // iterate loop upto found element or last element
  while (!found) {
    // check num is greater that current item
    if (newNum > +$ele.text()) {
      // then set found is true
      found = true;
      // check there is element next to it
    } else if ($ele.next().length) {
      // update element variable with sibling next to current element
      $ele = $ele.next();
      // check content is greater than elemnt and update flag
      if (newNum > +$ele.text())
        found = true;
      // if reached last element set flag to true, and last to true
    } else {
      found = true;
      last = true;
    }
  }
  // insert the element after the current element if `last` is true
  if (last)
    $ele.after(template);
  // else insert before the element
  else
    $ele.before(template);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-num="24">24</li>
  <li data-num="19">19</li>
  <li data-num="11">11</li>
  <li data-num="3">3</li>
</ul>
<button>+1</button>
```

Comment: @Samir : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about elegance. However, this should be a starting place:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRrMqN)

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var values = [];

  $('ul').children().each(function (i, e) {
    // get all the values and put them into an array
    values.push(parseInt($(e).attr('data-num'), 10));
  });

  var newNum=parseInt(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);

  // push this new number into the array
  values.push(newNum);

  // sort all the values desc.
  values.sort(function(a, b) {return -(a-b);});

  // clear out the ul
  $('ul').empty();

  // repopulate with li
  $.each(values, function (i,e) {
    var template='<li data-num="'+e+'">'+e+'</li>';
    //
    $('ul').append(template);  
  })

});
```

To me this is very readable (so you could say elegant). It is easy to understand, even if you looked back at it in 6 months time. Mainly because of self documenting code like `.each()` `.empty()` `.sort()`.

This is a lot less stateful as well. So you will get fewer bugs with this code (bugs introduced by flags, and other state).

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var newNum=parseInt(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
  var template='<li data-num="'+newNum+'">'+newNum+'</li>';

  // check if number is 20 then append the template after list containing 2
  if(newNum==20){
  console.log(template);
    $("li[data-num='24']").after().append(template);
  }
  else{
    $('ul').append(template);

  }

});
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP question. mainly due to the `if the random was 20`. he isn't saying when it is, or it is. He wants any number to be put in the correct place in list.